# How can I use filter enconding in OWSLib

Tags: python, geojson

I'm trying to retrieve a feature in JSON format, querying using owslib.fes constructors, to do that, I'm using PropertyIsEqualTo to pass the property name and value to filter, but the url string is malforming for a reason that I don't know how to solve.

**The code: **

```
from owslib.wfs import WebFeatureService, Authentication
from owslib.fes import PropertyIsEqualTo

auth = Authentication()
auth.verify = False

wfs2 = WebFeatureService(url="https://geoserver.car.gov.br/geoserver/sicar/ows", headers={'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'}, auth=auth, version='1.1.0' )

car = 'MT-5103700-92A39DC62FDF4D88874F218D41BE1C7F'
filter_car = PropertyIsEqualTo('cod_imovel', car);

wfs2.getfeature(typename='sicar:sicar_imoveis_mt', filter=filter_car, outputFormat='json');
```

**The error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gabrielubuntu/repos/pygeogis/app.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(wfs2.getfeature(typename='sicar:sicar_imoveis_mt', filter=filter_car, outputFormat='json'))
  File "/home/gabrielubuntu/repos/pygeogis/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/owslib/feature/wfs110.py", line 348, in getfeature
    u = openURL(base_url, data, method, timeout=self.timeout,
  File "/home/gabrielubuntu/repos/pygeogis/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/owslib/util.py", line 235, in openURL
    raise ServiceException('\n'.join([t.strip() for t in serviceException.itertext() if t.strip()]))
owslib.util.ServiceException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 38; Attribute name "object" associated with an element type "owslib.fes.PropertyIsEqualTo" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
Attribute name "object" associated with an element type "owslib.fes.PropertyIsEqualTo" must be followed by the ' = ' character.
```

**When I get the url from getGETgetFeatureRequest, the url is:**

```
https://geoserver.car.gov.br/geoserver/sicar/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&query=%3Cowslib.fes.PropertyIsEqualTo+object+at+0x7feb355cff70%3E&typename=sicar%3Asicar_imoveis_mt&outputFormat=json
```

Looks like the object of PropertyIsEqualTo is not constructing the string properly.

PS: I've tried to use **FilterRequest** too, but the result is the same

Answer (score 1):

I did it this way using requests with CQL_FILTER in the request parameters, and it worked perfectly for me:

```
import requests

import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)


class GetCarGeojson:
    def __init__(self, cod_imovel: str) -> None:
        self.cod_imovel = cod_imovel
        self.url = "https://geoserver.car.gov.br/geoserver/sicar/ows"

    def get_car(self) -> dict | None:
        params = self.__get_params()
        response = requests.get(self.url, params=params, verify=False)

        if response.status_code == 200:
            return response.json()
        else:
            print(f"Error: {response.status_code}")
            print(response.text)
            return None

    def __get_params(self) -> dict[str, str]:
        typename = self.__get_typename()
        
        return {
            "service": "WFS",
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "request": "GetFeature",
            "typeName": typename,
            "outputFormat": "application/json",
            "CQL_FILTER": f"cod_imovel IN ('{self.cod_imovel}')"
        }

    def __get_typename(self) -> str:
        # DF is the only state that needs to be in 
        # uppercase for the request to be successful.

        uf = self.cod_imovel[:2]
        if uf != 'DF':
            uf = uf.lower()

        return f"sicar:sicar_imoveis_{uf}"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    filtered_car = GetCarGeojson(
        cod_imovel='MT-5103700-92A39DC62FDF4D88874F218D41BE1C7F'
    ).get_car()

    print(filtered_car)
```